# Populating a datagridview from mysql database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Helllo,
I have a mySQL database and I want to pull information out of it via an SQL select query and then display this information in a datagride view. I have already written a database class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Data;
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Common;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace ExpTrackNEA

{
    class DatabaseManager
    {

        private MySqlConnection _Conn;
        public MySqlCommand Cmd;
        private MySqlDataAdapter _da;
        private DataTable _dt;
        private MySqlDataReader _dr;

        // This is the Database connection function
        public bool DBConnection()
        {
            // First step is to create an SSH Tunnel. This is done by calling the SSHTunnelCreate function
            if (SSHTunnelCreate() == true)
            {
                try // Start of Database connection Try attempt
                {
                    // Define the connection cerdentials
                    string ConnectionString = null;
                    ConnectionString = "server=SERVER;" +  // Database Address 
                        "               port=PORT;" +               // Port
                        "               database=DATABSAE;" + // Database Name
                        "               uid=USERNAME;" +              // Username
                        "               pwd=PASSWORd;";            // Password

                    // Define the connection
                    _Conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);

                    try // Attempt a connection
                    {
                        // Open the connection
                        _Conn.Open();


                        // Return true if connection is successful to the database
                        return true;

                    } // Rnd of database connection attempt

                    catch // Catach Database connection errors 
                    {
                        // Return False if a connection to the Database can't be made
                        return false;

                    } // End of Database connection errors catach


                } // End of Database connection Try attempt
                catch
                {

                    // If the connection is not successful it returns FALSE as it can't connect  
                    // to the database and the whole process is halted
                    return false;

                } // End of catch for Database Connection

            }// End of (SSHTunnelCreate() == true)
            else // If the SSH Tunnel Connection Failed
            {

                return false;

            }


        } // End of DBConnection Function



        private bool SSHTunnelCreate()
        {
            // Declaring the Connection string information
            ConnectionInfo ConnectionInformation = new ConnectionInfo(
                                                           "ssh.payneslan.co.uk",        // Host Name
                                                           22,                           // Connection Port
                                                           "UserNAME",                     // Username
                                                           new AuthenticationMethod[]{   // Define the Password
                                                            // Pasword based Authentication
                                                            // Define the connection information Username and Password respectfullt
                                                            new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("USERNAME","PASSWORD")
                                                           }
                                                         ); // End of ConnectionInformation

            using (var client = new SshClient(ConnectionInformation))
            {
                // Start an attempt to build an SSH Tunnel
                try
                { // SSH Tunnel Try Start
                    client.Connect();

                    if (client.IsConnected)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var PortFwdL = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 3306, "localhost", 3306);
                            //ForwardedPortLocal PortFwdL = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", Convert.ToUInt32(22), "127.0.0.1", Convert.ToUInt32(3306));

                            client.AddForwardedPort(PortFwdL);
                            PortFwdL.Start();

                            // Checking Port Forwarding is working
                            if (PortFwdL.IsStarted)
                            {
                                return true;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return false;
                            }

                        }

                        catch
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                    } // End of IF
                    else
                    {
                        // If the connection is not successful it returns FALSE as it now doesn't  
                        // have a secure connection to the server and now the database connection will
                        // halt.
                        return false;

                    } // End of Else
                } // End of Try
                catch // connection catch for SSH Tunnel creation
                {
                    // If the connection is not successful it returns FALSE as it now has a 
                    // secure connection to the server and now the database connection will
                    // halt
                    return false;

                } // End of connection catch for SSH Tunnel creation

            } // End of  using (var client = new SshClient(ConnectionInformation))

        } // End of SSHTunnelCreate Function.





        public void SQLQuery(string QueryText)
        {
            Cmd = new MySqlCommand(QueryText, _Conn);

        }




        public string strSQLQuery(string QueryText)
        {

            Cmd = new MySqlCommand(QueryText, _Conn);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(QueryText, _Conn);
          _dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

           string _value = null;

            while (_dr.Read())
            {
                _value = _dr.GetString(0);
            }

            _dr.Close();
            return _value;

        }





        // For The select queries
        public DataGrid QueryEx(string QueryText)
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from table1;", _Conn);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            //change name according to your datagridview
            DataGrid dataGridView1 = new DataGrid();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
           // dataGridView1.DataBind();
            return dataGridView1;
        }




        // For Insert,Update and Delete etc.
        public void NonQueryEx()
        {
            try
            {
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
               MessageBox.Show("An error occured when trying to perform this databse action" + "\n" +
                        "Your action was not completed.",
                        "Error executing Action",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);


            }
        }

    } // End Of Class DatabaseManager
}
```

And the what I want to do is pass the SQL query into the method queryEx and get this method to get all of the fields and return it in a state so that on the form I can simply put something like this.

`DGV_Users.DataSource = DataBase.QueryEx("SELECT * FROM`Users`");`

I have tried and failed to do this for a few days and have watched countless videos but I can't get any thing to work.

Thank you.

Comment: What issue you are facing with that code?

Comment: Fill: SelectedCommand.connectionproperty has not been initialized"

Comment: You will eventually regret making that database "helper" class.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of having everything inside separate functions and separate try/catch blocks, you can just have a single try/catch and use using statements.

Doing it this way also means that you can get rid of the large if/else statements and the following global variables:

```
private MySqlConnection _Conn;
public MySqlCommand Cmd;
private DataTable _dt;
```

So all in all your basic database query function should look like this:

```
public DataTable FillDataTable()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    try
    {    
        // Define the connection credentials
        string ConnectionString = "server=SERVER;port=PORT;database=DATABSAE;uid=USERNAME;pwd=PASSWORd;"; 
        string commandString = "Select * from table1;";

        //Use the connection
        using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            //Pass in command text and connection string
            using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(ConnectionString)
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.Text = commandString;

                //Any parameters in command string, add here
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SomeValue", value)

                using(MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    table.Load(reader);
                }
            }
        }           
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Catch any exceptions here
    }

    return table;
}
```

Then in your form class:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = FillDataTable();
```

Still this isn't really the most optimal way. You could use the [DbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) class, so not to rely specifically on MySql.

Also you should clean up your code a bit more such as your variable naming conventions and your functions. For example what is the purpose of this function?

```
public void SQLQuery(string QueryText)
{
    Cmd = new MySqlCommand(QueryText, _Conn);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help this code has helped to fix my issue.I am now working on cleaning up my code.